# JQuery's multiDatesPicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

I am trying to code a very simple build of the MultiDatesPicker jquery plugin. But I'm getting the following errors:

**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiDatesPicker is not a function**

Here's what I have so far:

## Script and CSS files in head

```
<head>
    <script src="~/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI-latest/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI-latest/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css">

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

## Jquery Script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker();
    });
</script>
```

## HTML

```
<input id="mdp-demo">
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to call jQueryUI *before* you call the datePicker script. It depends on the library. Just change the order of your scripts to have jQueryUI *before* multidatespicker.

From the docs:
[image]

https://portail.ac-amiens.fr/imagin/ressources/webfusion/jqueryUI-component/multidatespicker/

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I edited the order of my scripts, and it still didn't render. I'm no longer getting the "cannot read property 'multiDatesPicker' of undefined" error, but I am still getting the error, "multiDatesPicker is not a function.“

I edited the head element in the OP as well so you can see what I did.

Comment: Ok, so it *did* work, in the sense that it is no longer undefined (the dependency is fixed). This is a *new* problem, which I'll see if I can help you with.

Comment: I’m sorry I wasn’t totally clear with that. Yes, progress was made.

Comment: I'm not being cranky. It's just SO has a *very* strict set of guidelines as to what questions/answers are. Looking at your HTML, it seems as though you don't have the input set to a date/text. I've never used multidatespicker, but that might be causing you issues. Can you post a snippet here for troubleshooting?

Comment: I changed it to a type="date" but that didn't change the error "multiDatesPicker is not a function." The input is just free floating and gets put in a <main> element that gets scaffolded by my ASP.NET MVC project, so I don't know how helpful a snippet would be. [Here's a link to the HTML](https://github.com/wggreen/BackEndCapstone/blob/master/BackEndCapstone/Views/User/Index.cshtml)